# How do I set tool hotkeys to not take immediate action?

Tags: transforms, shortcut, gizmo

Whenever I select an object in blender, I want the the tool hotkeys (G for move, R for rotate, etc) to have the same effect as when I click them (just showing the appropriate gizmo), instead of for example pressing G and the object being moved with my cursor, or pressing S and the scale being attached to my cursor's movement. How am I able to fix this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: ok, i know, you don't wanna hear that. But i don't think you will use the gizmo after using Blender for a little bit longer. Because mouse + keyboard are much quicker and more accurate than using gizmo.

Comment: I appreciate your input, I really do. But how much is a little bit longer? I've been using blender semi-seriously for a  bit over a year and a half now and I've always preferred the gizmo. I assume you mean using the coordinate hotkeys though (G for move and then pressing X for X axis, Y for Y axis, etc), correct? I could do it like that but I really prefer the gizmo most of the times. Nonetheless, thank you!